# MySQL Stored procedure with local variable not working in LINUX

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling with a simple stored procedure, that I've reduced to this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RemoveDuplicateModules() 
BEGIN 
 SET @myvar=1; 
End;
```

When I run this in the MySQL CLI I get: parameter `@myvar` has not been created. I'm struggling cause in windows it works fine!

> mysql --version = 5.6.33

Answer (score 1):

Works for me (debian, mysql 5.6.25):

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE RemoveDuplicateModules()
    -> BEGIN
    ->  SET @myvar=1;
    -> End;
    -> //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,66 sec)

mysql> call RemoveDuplicateModules();
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> select @myvar ;
+--------+
| @myvar |
+--------+
|      1 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0,02 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the problem here was not that the procedure I posted was failing, but since it was being executed in a larger context, a big file with a lot of code from a lot of people, a previous lack of a commit made my procedure to fail. Anyway, thanks for the help!